# Building bullet physics as shared libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cmake, 64-bit, shared-libraries, bullet

I'm using the latest github version from https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3

To generate the visual studio solution, I've used the 'vs2010.bat' located in bullet3/build3. This sets it up as static libraries however. If I change the configuration type to dynamic, the .dlls are generated properly, but no .lib-files.

I've also tried using CMake with "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS" enabled, but again, no .lib-files are generated.

What's the proper way of building bullet as shared libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible using Visual Studio on Windows to generate import libs (.lib) when using shared libraries for Bullet. The reasons is that no symbols are explicitly exported. Shared libraries work fine using gcc or clang on Linux and Mac OSX. It would require quite a bit of work to instrument the code to fix this issue.

See also https://cmake.org/Wiki/BuildingWinDLL